# Error 535 while setting up nodemailer with GoDaddy

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I'm wondering if anyone has figured out how to use GoDaddy hosted email with nodemailer. I have an email submission box from my contact form, and it triggers the following script:

```
function sendEmail ( to, subject, body ) {

 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Godaddy',
  host: "relay-hosting.secureserver.net",  
  port: 465,
  secureConnection: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'email@godaddydomain.com',
    pass: 'password'
  }
  });

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'email@godaddydomain.com',
  to: to,
  subject: subject,
  text: body
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
}
```

I've tried a few different options, and made sure my ports are all open, but I'm having a hard time with the authentication. I keep getting errors like this:

```
{ Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication Failed for email@godaddydomain.com. User does not have any relays assigned.
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/www/node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:577:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/var/www/node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1306:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/var/www/node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:349:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/var/www/node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:733:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/var/www/node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:529:14)
    at Socket._socket.on.chunk (/var/www/node/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:481:47)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535 Authentication Failed for email@godaddydomain.com. User does not have any relays assigned.',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like this error is related to the hostname. Try this one:

```
var transporter2 = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Godaddy',
    host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",  
    secureConnection: true,
    port: 465
})
```

Comment: I don't know why, but my previous host was `smtpout.asia.secureserver.net` and it was suddenly throws 535 error. Now, I changed it to `smtpout.secureserver.net` and it worked! I still not know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. I changed configuration to the following:

```
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",
  secure: true,
  secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
  tls: {
    ciphers: "SSLv3",
  },
  requireTLS: true,
  port: 465,
  debug: true,
  auth: {
    user: "xxxx@yyyy.com",
    pass: "pass",
  },
});
```

It worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's still looking for this (as I have been the last few days!), I found all the server information GoDaddy was suggesting was completely wrong. Found the answer in cPanel - if you go to the main bit, and click on 'Email Accounts', on your account it should have an option on the right saying 'Connect Devices'. Click on that and it'll give you the correct server and port information for what you need, which for me ended up being this:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "sxb1plzcpnl487525.prod.sxb1.secureserver.net",
  secure: true,
  secureConnection: true,
  port: 465,
  auth: {user: "yourcpanelusername@yourdomain.com", pass: "yourcpanelpassword"},
  tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
});
```

Took me forever to find that specific weird server it needed. Hope this helps. Apologies for formatting, it's my first post here but I wanted to help as I've spent days on this now.

Answer (score 0):

**If this code can help someone, he works for me to GoDaddy.**

"nodemailer": "^6.9.7",

- Check your auth credentials (user, pass)
- Check transporter configurations
- Check your .env match with your process.env

.env

```
AUTH_HOST=smtpout.secureserver.net
AUTH_USER=xyz@xyz.com
AUTH_PASS=xyz
FROM_EMAIL=xyz@xyz.com
TO_EMAIL=xyz@xyz.com
```

server.js

```
const sanitizedFormData = {
  nom: xss(formData.nom),
  email: xss(formData.email),
  sujet: xss(formData.sujet),
  message: xss(formData.message),
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: process.env.AUTH_HOST,
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.AUTH_USER,
    pass: process.env.AUTH_PASS,
  },
  debug: true,
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: process.env.FROM_EMAIL,
  to: process.env.TO_EMAIL,
  replyTo: sanitizedFormData.email,
  subject: sanitizedFormData.sujet,
  html: htmlToSend,
};

// verify connection configuration
transporter.verify(function (error, success) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
  }
});

const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

console.log("Email sent:", info.response);
```